# Wince Call CreateMutex in Kernel

Tags: windows-ce

I need to share a resource between the OEM Abstraction Layer (OAL) and a driver that will run outside of the kernel.  To share the resource I will create a mutex.  When I call [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488798.aspx) (or any other function in coredll.lib) from the OAL I get a prefetch abort exception.

How do you create a mutex in the OAL (kernel space) in Windows Compact 7?

Comment: While I cannot help you, I think you would be better off to edit and shorten your question and just ask how to create a mutex lock. I find your question to be rather difficult to read.

Comment: @Georg Schölly: Thank you for the feedback.  I've narrowed the question quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a mutex, but you can use a critical section.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478303.aspx
Critical section work between threads inside the same process and if your driver is a kernel mode driver and not a user mode one, it will run inside nk.exe, same process as OAL.
Instead of sharing the critical section (not easy since they can't be named) you can implement a couple of kernel IOCTLs to Enter/Leave it.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I was able to add an IOCTL to the OAL and use a critical section just like you said.  Since I am using Windows CE 7 I had to explicitly allow the IOCTL to pass through the OAL in SRC/OAL/OALIOCTL/oalioctl.cpp IOControl function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the oaliotcl.dll part. My fault :(